# How to create a matrix (5 x 5) with strings, without using numpy? (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x

So I am creating a memory matching game, in which a player will pair two words from a list of words.

I am trying to create a 2D 5x5 matrix with strings without using numpy.

I've tried with for i in range(x): for j in range(x), but I can't get it to work.

So how do I do?

Comment: Why without numpy? Numpy has many benefits, such as implementations in C (cython) rather than slow native python...

Comment: @MatBailie well, I've tried to install the module to idle.. but always get an error "no module named numpy"

Comment: You're going to need to install alsorts in the future. Don't avoid numpy because you can't figure out how to do install it, fix whatever you're doing wrong and open yourself up to the massive world of python modules.  (Maybe THAT should be a question you should ask on SO?)

Comment: @MatBailie I installed numpy now, how do I create a 5x5 matrix with it?

Answer (score 2):

Python doesn't have a built in matrix type like that, but you can pretty much emulate it with a list of lists, or with a dict keyed by ordered pairs.

---

Here's the list of lists approach using a list comprehension inside a list comprehension:

```
from pprint import pprint
matrix = [[c for c in line] for line in '12345 abcde ABCDE vwxyz VWXYZ'.split()]
pprint(matrix)
```

The result, pretty-printed.

```
[['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'],
 ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
 ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
 ['v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'],
 ['V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']]
```

You can split on different characters in the inner or outer loops.

```
matrix = [[word for word in line.split()] for line in 'foo bar;spam eggs'.split(';')]
```

You get and set elements with a double lookup, like `matrix[2][3]`.

Results can vary with pprint depending on the width of the words. List of lists are pretty easy to print in matrix form though. `.join()` is the inverse of `.split()`.

```
print('\n'.join('\t'.join(line) for line in matrix))
```

And the result in this case,

```
foo     bar
spam    eggs
```

This just uses a tab character `'\t'`, which may or may not produce good results depending on your tab stops and word withs. You can control this more precisely by using the justify string methods or `.format()` or f-strings with specifiers.

---

Here's one with the pair-keyed dict. Recall that tuples of hashable types are hashable too.

```
{(i, j): 'x' for i in range(5) for j in range(5)}
```

You get and set elements with a pair lookup, like `matrix[2, 3]`.

Again, you can use words.

```
{(i, j): word
 for i, line in enumerate("""\
1 2 3 4 5
foo bar baz quux norlf
FOO BAR BAZ QUUX NORLF
spam eggs sausage bacon ham
SPAM EGGS SAUSAGE BACON HAM""".split('\n'))
 for j, word in enumerate(line.split())}
```

Comment: I did a list of list, but not by using list comprehension. However, I got the result I wanted. But whenever I try to print the matrix without the commas etc using rjust(), the matrix becomes a vertical list of all the elements. How do I tackle this?